# Cytoscape.js layout not running

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I can't make layout running from scipt. I added these lines

```
var lay = cy.layout({name:'grid'})
lay.run()
```

But nothing happens.
If I manually go to a browser console after page rendering and run that same commands everything works. 
I expect this to be a newbie JS question so any direction towards relevant info is also appreciated.

Comment: I saw the same problem. It seems like you have to generate layout object and call run function at the same line like suggested in the answers. "cy.layout({ name: 'circle' }).run();" It is weird

Answer (score 3):

It's simple one line statement for run layout as below.

```
cy.layout({ name: 'circle' }).run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like layout should be synchronized with graph placement, for example

```
$.getJSON(
  "http://path/to/json-with-nodes",
  function (data) {
    cy.json(data);
    lay = cy.layout({name:'random'});
    lay.run();
  }
);
```